# Deprecation of ComponentFactoryResolver when providing additional data to the component

Tags: angular

I have a component that renders a child component that it receives as an `@Input()` and I'm receiving a deprecation warning.  I tried following other SO questions but mine seems a bit unique as I need to pass additional data to this child component.

Previously I had the following:

```
constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent()
  }

  dismiss(data = null) {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss(data)
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.childComponent.component)
    const viewContainerRef = this.componentHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear()

    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (componentRef.instance as GenericData).data = this.childComponent.data;
    (componentRef.instance as GenericData).modalCtrl = this.modalCtrl;
  }
```

How might I refactor this using `ViewContainerRef` and `createComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass the component to `createComponent` :

```
 const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.childComponent.component);
```

Comment: I meant, how do I provide data to the component like I did in my question

Comment: the same way, using `componentRef.instance`